# What is the difference between mxmlc and amxmlc when compile an swf of air mobile project for ios?

Tags: actionscript-3, mxmlc

I could use the same way compile an swf with mxmlc and amxmlc:

```
amxmlc -load-config obj\config.xml

mxmlc -load-config obj\config.xml
```

*But, What is the difference?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there is no functional difference between those.

Adobe's "[Building Adobe AIR Applications](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f2012b5a4128cca83a39-8000.html)" document says this about the difference between amxmlc and mxmlc:

> The only difference between the Flex and the AIR versions of the
>   utilities is that the AIR versions load the configuration options from
>   the air-config.xml file instead of the flex-config.xml file.

Adobe's "[Using mxmlc, the application compiler | About the application compiler options](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7a92.html)" document says this about `load-config` :

> Specifies the location of **the configuration file** that defines compiler
>   options.
>
> If you specify a configuration file, you can override individual
>   options by setting them on **the command line**.
>
> All relative paths in the configuration file are relative to the
>   location of the configuration file itself.
>
> **Use the += operator** to chain this configuration file **to other**
>   configuration files.

Adobe's "[Flex compilers | About configuration files](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fca.html)" document says this about `load-config`:

> You can, however, create a custom configuration file and pass it to
>   the Flash Builder compilers by using the load-config option.